# Data Retrieved From Fire base database is showing in drop down of spinner but selected item not setting to spinner

Tags: java, android

This is my main Activity. XML file is also provided. I am Retrieving Data from Fire base Database in a Spinner. It is Viewing in Drop down menu but the selected item is not setting to the Spinner.Class showFacultySpinner is being used in the main activity to retrieve data from Firebase. If someone want to also check that, i will provide.

```
public class TestSpinnerAddCourse extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {

    DatabaseReference databaseReference;
    showFacultySpinner showFacultySpinner;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_spinner_add_course);


        databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        showFacultySpinner = new showFacultySpinner(databaseReference);

// Spinner element
        Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);

        // Spinner click listener
        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);


        // Creating adapter for spinner
        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = 
            new ArrayAdapter<String>(
                this, 
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, 
                showFacultySpinner.retreive()
            );

        // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
        dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        // attaching data adapter to spinner
        spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
// On selecting a spinner item
        String item = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(), "Selected: " + item , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

    }
}
```

This is my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:padding="10dip"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

  >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dip"
        android:text="Category:"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You see all of your items at the drop down of the spinner and when you clicking on one of them the drop down closes and you don't see the item clicked on the spinner placeholder ?

Comment: Thanks for your response...but the problem is solved....I was not adding initial value to be displayed in placeholde of spinner. I diid this by adding a intial value value to array list in showFacultySpinner class

Comment: glad to hear , I'm guessing that `showFacultySpinner.retreive()` is an async task (getting data from firebase) so its also good practice to keep in mind to create adapter after these task are completed and the data at client side . give it a try

Comment: I would give it a try...dear...thanks